# How to abort uploading a stream to google storage in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, google-cloud-storage, nodejs-stream

- Interaction with Cloud Storage is performed using the official [Node.js Client library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage).
- Output of an external executable (`ffmpeg`) through [`fluent-ffmpeg`](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) is piped to a writable stream of a Google Cloud Storage object using [`createWriteStream`].(https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream).
- Executable (`ffmpeg`) can end with an error. In this case the file is created on Cloud Storage with 0 length.
- I want to abort uploading on the command error to avoid finalizing an empty storage object.

**What is the proper way of aborting the upload stream?**

Current code (just an excerpt):

```js
ffmpeg()
    .input(sourceFile.createReadStream())
    .output(destinationFile.createWriteStream())
    .run();
```

Files are instances of https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/storage/file.

Comment: Not sure about aborting the stream, but you can check the non-zero return code of FFmpeg process for a failed FFmpeg run to trigger deleting the 0-byte file.

Comment: Thanks, as a workaround might be suitable. Yet still I hope there is a way of aborting the upload operation.